# Problema em deixar largura do campo automática em layout responsivo

Tags: html, css, css3, layout-responsivo, layout

Tenho a seguinte situação..
Estou trabalhando em um layout responsivo que possui três colunas, sidebar esquerda, centro e direita...
Acontece que dentro da sidebar direita existe um campo de texto e ao lado deve existir um botão submit... Esse botão nunca pode quebrar a linha, por isso usei na div (dentro do sidebar) onde está este formulário a propriedade **white-space: nowrap;**

O problema é que eu gostaria que o elemento botão ficasse fixo na sua largura e o campo texto ficasse flexível, mas quando as dimensões ficam variadas isso não acontece, ou ele cresce demais, estourando o layout ou fica pequeno demais, sobrando espaço dentro do sidebar. Existe alguma forma de resolver isso?

o código é o seguinte:

```
div#sidebar {
  width: 23%;
}

div#sidebar div#searchbox {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div#sidebar div#searchbox input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
}

div#sidebar div#searchbox input[type="submit"] {
  width: 85px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
   <div id="searchbox">
       <input type="text" name="query" />
       <input type="submit" name="btn-submit" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Coloque o html também.

Comment: pronto, conforme pedido, coloquei...

Comment: Imagine que dentro do elemento sidebar, vc terá mais duas colunas, uma para o input text e outra para o submit, a mágica aqui é deixar uma fixa e outra responsiva. Veja esse link para uma explicação mais detalhada.
http://www.todoespacoonline.com/w/2014/04/05/layout-responsivo/

Comment: Qual navegador você está usando? Sua tentativa parece funcionar: [dá uma olhada nesse fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLwa5zna/).

Comment: A sua aplicação vai ser executada em navegadores anteriores ao IE9? Porque uma alternativa é o uso do Flexbox em CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Olhe esse exemplo em que uso uma tabela para alcançar seu objetivo:

```css
table{
    width: 100%;
}
td{
    border: 0;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
input[type="submit"], input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
}
.parse{
     min-width: 70px;
     width: 70px;   
}
.full{
    width: 1fr;   
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="full" >
            <input type="text">
        </td>
        <td  class="parse" >
            <input type="submit">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Uso da tabela é justificado por conta da propriedade `width`, com o atributo `1fr`.
Esse atributo faz com que a coluna (ou a linha) a que ele seja aplicado, tenha o restante do tamanho da tela, levando em consideração as outras colunas.

Com isso basta colocar as `inputs` com `width: 100%` e o tamanho delas você escolhe aplicando o `min-width` nas colunas em que elas estão.

Tente redimensionar no JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/nvavm90z/2/.

Comment: Eu ia responder, mas acho que essa resposta do Samir Braga atende o que a pergunta precisa.

Answer (score 0):

Alterei um pouco a estrutura do html para chegar ao resultado final, mas aqui funcionou bem.

```css
    #sidebar {
        display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
        display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
        display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
        display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
        display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
        border: 2px solid red;
        width: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
    <div style="width: 100%;">
        <input type="text" name="query" style="width: 100%;" />
    </div>
    <div style="border: 2px solid blue;">
        <input type="submit" name="btn-submit" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Já que você está fazendo um layout *responsivo*, você devia pensar de maneira responsiva. Quando a tela for pequena demais para que sua sidebar não se comporte como deveria, use uma sidebar off-canvas (pesquise sobre isso) ou faça ela aparecer por cima do conteudo central.